# Almost Diophantine approximation

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, approximation, diophantine-approximation

We have an algebraic number $a$ and a real number $b$. Can the following inequality have infinitely many solutions for $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

$$ \{an\} \in [b - \frac{1}{2^n}, b + \frac{1}{2^n}] $$

Where ${x}$ denotes the fractional part of x, ${x} = x - [x]$.

**Background**. I encountered this problem when I was dealing with some kronecker approximations, I wanted to show that for a given point $(b_1t \mod 2\pi, b_2t \mod 2\pi)$ where $b_1,b_2$ are algebraic numbers who are linearly independent over rational numbers, one can not get exponentially close to a given fixed point $(\phi_1,\phi_2) \in [-1,1]^2$. Some special cases of this problem could be solved by Baker but I was unable to solve it in the general case.

Comment: To ensure that $\lfloor{na}\rfloor$ is defined, it should be specified that $a$ is real. Also, to avoid trivial solutions (using, for example, $b=0$), you should require $a\not\in\mathbb{Q}$.